# c++ pass two integers into queue

Tags: c++, queue

i have created a queue class using array, that must hold two integers at most. But how do i pass two integers to the array at once? using bool Queue::enqueue(int, int)

Also i need a dequeue() which prints both integers and throws them away from the queue. Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

```
class Queue {
private:
  int * table;
  int front;
  int length;
  const int size=2;
public:
  Queue(int n);
  ~Queue();
  bool isEmpty();
  bool enqueue(int, int);
  bool dequeue();
  void print();
};

Queue::Queue(int n){
n=size;
length=0;
front=0;
table=new int[n];
}

Queue::~Queue(){
delete [] table;
}

bool Queue::isEmpty(){
if(length==size)
    return false;
else
    return true;
}

bool Queue::enqueue(int , int){
if (length == size)
  return -1; // Error, Queue is full
now i need to pass two integers if it it empty
```

Comment: How would you do it with one int?

Comment: Make your queue generic and use `std::pair<int,int>`?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to play with the definition of a Queue? Seems like there is a flaw in your design. However I have still written a working code using a vector which will solve your purpose (though I doubt about what you want to achieve by adding/removing 2 items in enqueue/dequeue operations)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Queue {

  vector<int> table;
  const int CAPACITY = 2;

public:
  bool isEmpty();
  bool enqueue(int, int);
  void dequeue();
  void print();
};

bool Queue::isEmpty(){
    if(table.size())
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

bool Queue::enqueue(int a, int b){
    if (table.size())
        return false; // Error, Queue is full
    table.push_back(a);
    table.push_back(b);
    return true;
}

void Queue::dequeue(){
    if(!table.size())
        return; //queue is empty
    table.pop_back();
    table.pop_back();
}

void Queue::print(){
    if(!table.size()){
        cout << "Queue is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << table[0] << "," << table[1] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    //Make a variable of our container
    Queue queue;
    queue.enqueue(1,2);
    queue.print();
    queue.dequeue();
    queue.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is probably something like a homework problem, I don't think the instructor for this person would appreciate a vector as the internal data structure for the creation of a queue. If the standard library were to be allowed to be used, why not just use a `std::queue` or `std::dequeue`?

Comment: Well, in that case, I think I helped an unethical activity. Homework is supposed to be done by the student himself without external help ;-)

Comment: For situations like this, it is better to just not answer the question itself, and instead encourage the student to figure out the solution himself. Don't just post code, maybe give an idea to what the person can do to solve the problem.